# can I make banner wider in carousel

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS. How can I make 'Welcome to JWellness' as a full-size banner? When it's in the `<div class="carousel`..."> tag. when I'm trying to use css : mix-blend-mode: screen; the output result is show me only 'TO' text not showing all 'WELCOME TO JWELLNESS'

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.banner .text1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.514);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.video-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

#sidebarCollapse {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
}

.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Carousel Text</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5 d-block w-100">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-4"></div>
      <div class="banner" style="border-radius: 15px">
        <div class="video-container">
          <video autoplay muted loop>
              <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Sail-Away.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
              <h2 class="text1">Welcome <br />to<br />JwellNess</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and add details and clarity to the question. Your question is too broad and misses the necessary details. Beyond that, your target audience here are developers. They know what HTML and CSS are! Last but not least, format your code correctly. Adding double linebreaks everywhere makes your code unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code and check that it fulfills your requirements. in this example you can give **position** css for the banner text so then can not take the banner text height.

```css
.banner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.banner iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.banner .text1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 1000;
    font-size: 10vw;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.514);
}

.video-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

#sidebarCollapse {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

#content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100vh;
}

.box1 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.486);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 3.7em auto;
    padding: 2em;
    color: white;
    border: 2em solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 5px 3px 30px rgba(241, 234, 234, 0.735);
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 100%;
}

.blockquote-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.blockquote-container blockquote {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Carousel Text</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/sidemenunmainpage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/jwellNessText.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/JwellNessText2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/thaiDCR.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/firstText.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/quote.css" />
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5 d-block w-100">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mt-4"></div>
            <div class="banner" style="border-radius: 15px">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <video autoplay muted loop>
                        <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Sail-Away.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
                            <h2 class="text1">
                                Welcome <br />to<br />
                                JwellNess
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
                            <blockquote>
                                สร้างอนาคตด้วยเทคโนโลยีการออกแบบของญี่ปุ่นร่วมกับการใช้ IoT
                                นำไปสู่การพัฒนาความสำเร็จในอุตสาหกรรมหลักชั้นนำของญี่ปุ่น
                                ส่งเสริมบริษัทญี่ปุ่นด้วยโซลูชัน IoT ล่าสุด
                            </blockquote>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you almost correct but I want to use 'mix-blend-mode: screen;' with your code but when I put 'mix-blend-mode: screen;' in your code its almost perfect. but your code really useful Thanks.

Comment: if you want to use 'mix-blend-mode: screen;' then just add the CSS .banner .carousel-item {
    backface-visibility: visible;
} so you can easily manage it.